# How to get the display name of a process?

Tags: .net, vb.net, process

I am developing an application that needs to get the display name of an process (like "Notepad" or "Microsoft Edge"), like in Task Manager. How do I do that?

**EDIT:**
I want to get the Display Name of **all processes**, not just the processes if an window.

Comment: [**Process.MainWindowTitle**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: And what if the process has no window?

Comment: Then it has no "display name". What you see in the task manager is either the window title or the .exe-file's "Title" or "Description" attribute.